# How to find the current values of the local variables of some general method?

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, java-11, jvm-bytecode

I am trying to write a utility method that would capture a snapshot of the current values of the local variables (if I understand it correctly, from a bytecode point of view, these include also the method parameters) of the method within which it is called.

Here is the info I want to capture for each local variable:

```
class VariableInfo
{
    public String name;
    public String desc;
    public Object value;

    VariableInfo(String name, String desc, Object value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I was able to find the name and desc (type) using `ASM`...

**QUESTION:** How can I find **the runtime current value** of a local variable, e.g. by its index? Is it possible to do it by `ASM`? Some other way? Obviously this data is updated in the relevant stack frame, but how can I access it?

Here is the general method that I have so far:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.objectweb.asm.tree.*;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter;

public Map<String, List<VariableInfo>> recordMethodVariableValues() throws IOException {

    //TraceHelper is a utility class, to let me look one stack frame above the current one (i.e. the method that called this utility method)
    int depth = 1;
    String className = TraceHelper.getClassName(depth);
    String methodName = TraceHelper.getMethodName(depth);

    InputStream is = readClass(className);
    ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(is);

    ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
    reader.accept((ClassVisitor) classNode, 0);

    //Since the method may be overloaded, and I look it up by name, I may find several matching methods... is there a better way to identify only the encapsulating method?
    Map<String, List<VariableInfo>> methodInfos = new HashMap<>();
    int counter = 0;

    for (final MethodNode mn : classNode.methods) {
        if (methodName.equals(mn.name))
        {
            System.out.println("Looking up variables of method: " + mn.name);
            List<VariableInfo> variableInfos = new ArrayList<>();
            for (LocalVariableNode n : mn.localVariables)
            {
                System.out.println("Looking up value of variable: " + n.name);
                //TODO... How to find the local variable current value, e.g. by its index?
                variableInfos.add(new VariableInfo(n.name, n.desc, getLocalVariableValueByIndex(n.index)));
            }
            methodInfos.put(mn.name + "-" + ++counter, variableInfos);
        }
    }

    return methodInfos;
}
```

Comment: Short answer is: if you want a specific value in the optimized code created by the runtime, i think you can't as they may not exist in the optimized form. If you pin(like you would do in a debugger) you don't get the real dump but something different, that is ensured to have your value. So looking at it changes the internal representation.

Comment: @kai What do you mean by "something different"? If it has the correct value at the current point, then that's what I need. Any links to actual code examples that try to carry out this feat? I am not a bytecode expert.

Comment: if the runtime is able to it removes unecessary stuff to  optimize. As long as you dont look at it, it gets optimized away. If you look at it you need it and it cannot optimize it away so the result differs. (For a simple example that shows my point).

Comment: Also the runtime creates binary(!) code from the byte code that is adapted according to the results of profiling.

Comment: But i may have misunderstood your question/ be on the wrong track and you want something else ..

Comment: @kai I don't understand your terminology. Generally, the values of local variables are not in the Java code/bytecode/machine code... they are in the local variable part of an execution stack frame. It might be that some local variables will not appear there due to the bytecode being optimized... but the fact that I insert code to look them up (i.e. my utility method) should prevent this. I am asking how to practically look them up. It is done in debugging and in some frameworks.

Comment: yes, thats my point - see the exclamation behind binary - that is native machine code in oposite to byte code: the whole stackframe might not exist if a method was inlined ...

Comment: That was indeed a very expressive exclamation mark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188198/discussion-between-rapt-and-kai).

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean with “find the current value of a local variable, e.g. by its index”. Do you want to predict the value by only looking at the code via ASM? Or, do you want to report the actual runtime value a variable has during the code’s execution? In the latter case, you have to insert instructions reading the variable and passing it to the particular reporting method.

Comment: @Holger I mean  the latter case: whenever I call my utility method, I want it to  report the actual runtime value a local variable has during the code’s execution. Could you post here any actual code example or direct me to any other example here on SO or somewhere else?

Comment: This is still unclear. What does “whenever I call my utility method” mean? Which code is supposed to call the method and which local variable is meant by “the actual runtime value a local variable”?

Comment: @Holger It is explained in the first paragraph of my OP. To clarify: every application may call the utility method explicitly (i.e. in its Java source code). It is essentially a logging method. The same way that Java source code may call to `System.out.println(...)` or to `Logger.log(...)`. At runtime, when the application is executing, if my utility method is being invoked, it should inspect and return the current runtime values of the local variables of the encapsulating method (i.e. the method within which my utility method is called). I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Only debuggers can do that. But since the caller does already know its variables, it would be much simpler to construct the information right in the caller. You could use ASM to transform invocations of your utility method into code doing that, but this transformation would need to be done before the execution of the code.

Comment: @Holger I have read that there are two basic approaches to implement such a utility method. 1. In the bytecode detect every case when the local variables are updated (inserted), and then update the new values in some global storage. Then when the utility method is called, it will simply look at this storage. The disadvantage is that it's a lot of overhead done for every method in the source code, even when it's not required. 2. Only inspect the values of local variables when the utility method is invoked.... I do not know how to do it. I prefer the second approach because it is less overhead.

Comment: @rapt as said, you can’t do the second approach, but you can improve the first approach to only take actions when the code would call your method. Then, you don’t need a global store. But you have to modify the code before its execution.